# Own file extension - behaviour like picture in OS

Tags: image, file, operating-system, icons

I'd like to have my own file extension which holds my own data. With double clicking it will start with my own software. So far no problem.

How can i save a picture in that file (metadata?) in a way that it is shown in the OS (Windows, Mac) like a .jpg in the preview window (big symbols in windows, or in the window of the space key preview in macOS)?
The image is generated by my software and therefore is for the user to have a quick info of the internal data...

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems sometimes allow you to write plugins that read your file data and then convert it to a form that the OS knows how to display in a thumbnail. As for getting your file format to open in existing applications such as Photoshop, this will generally not be possible unless the application developers either choose to add support for your format themselves or allow you to write a plugin, which you will need to do yourself. Most existing file formats that are supported natively in operating systems and user programs have well-known, popular standards and users expect that their software will support these formats by default.